# Weird typescript compiler behavior with decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

i got this example of using decorators from official site about typescript

```ts
function sealed(constructor: Function) {
    Object.seal(constructor);
    Object.seal(constructor.prototype);
    
}

@sealed
class Dot {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

and when i run it i get this error with enabled `"experimentalDecorators": true` and `"target": "es5"`

```txt
decorators.ts:7:2 - error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1.

7 @sealed
   ~~~~~~


Found 1 error in decorators.ts:7
```

but when i compile it with `tsc --target ES5 --experimentalDecorators` it works fine
please help me understand why

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any typos in `"experimentalDecorators": true` in your tsconfig? This error makes sense in TS 5.0 or later with `experimentalDecorators` option disabled: in this case TS uses the stage 3 version of decorators proposal, where the decorator indeed needs two arguments. With `experimentalDecorators` on, it uses the outdated stage 2 version of decorators, so if this error occurs, then the compiler must think that `experimentalDecorators` is off somehow

Comment: Also not sure if you are reading the old documentation on purpose or not, but just in case: this version of decorators is outdated. TS 5.0 introduced the new syntax for decorators that follows the now stage 3 proposal and which is going to be implemented in JS. This version doesn't need the `experimentalDecorators` flag.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.